# If Authorize fail in Web-api (asp.net) , browser show basic authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, identity

I just want to get Error Message.
But application show It needs basic login.

How can I pass it?

[image: Error]

**AccountServiceController**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("UserRoles")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserRoles(string userName){
        //my code
}
```

**Strat.Auth**

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(1)
        }); 
        var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            Provider = new DrDB.Identity.Infrastructure.SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);

        OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
```

Comment: Need more detials , more code about how you setup authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way.

The WebAPI shouldn't be displaying the logon prompt - the calling application should.

If you check the response that the WebAPI is returning, it's likely a 401 (unauthorized).

The caller can check for a 401 response, and display whatever login page it needs to.

Comment: I don't need login page, but when web-api return 401 then appear that login prompt. And When I test on Visual studio, not appear. But It appear when I publish on test server.